# Hibernate 4.3.9 and mapping enums

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums

I am currently working on upgrading Hibernate for a project, from 3.x to 4.3.9, and I am running into some strange error. I have several enum values in entities, all mapped as `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`. In previous versions of Hibernate this would be mapped as `VARCHAR(255)`. But now, using MySQL, Hibernate tries to map it as a `tinyblob`, which makes the validation fail.

From what I can tell from the `MySQLDialect`, the only way Hibernate can believe this to be a `tinyblob` is if the type is mapped to `Types.VARBINARY`. But I can't really see a reason for it to be mapped as anything other than a `VARCHAR`.

When looking at a previous version of `Hibernate`, `4.1.1`, I can see the following code in `SimpleValueBinder`:

```
if ( enumType != null ) {
    if ( javax.persistence.EnumType.ORDINAL.equals( enumType ) ) {
        typeParameters.setProperty( EnumType.TYPE, String.valueOf( Types.INTEGER ) );
}
else if ( javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING.equals( enumType ) ) {
    typeParameters.setProperty( EnumType.TYPE, String.valueOf( Types.VARCHAR ) );
}
else {
    throw new AssertionFailure( "Unknown EnumType: " + enumType );
}
```

This makes sense, and will make the type a `VARCHAR`. But, in the same class of `4.3.9`, this construct is missing. Also, it looks like the class has been refactored quite heavily.

Could this be a bug in version `4.3.9`of `Hibernate`?

Update: Strangely, I get exactly the same error with Hibernate `4.3.10` and `MSSQL`.

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone with the answer?  I am using HB 5.0.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by introducing my own Hiberante-dialect, containing the following line:

```
registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, 255, "varchar(255)");
```

More of a workaround than a fix, though..